# Return hazelcast data as json if read from REST

Tags: spring, rest, hazelcast

I implemented session replication using hazelcast on my spring boot app. And also exposed hazelcast data through rest by enabling '**hazelcast.rest.enabled**' property.

I am saving some java objects with Portable serialization on to session as attributes. Session attributes saved under SessionState object, this object is returned if I query hazelcast map using cookie id.

If I access hazelcast using REST client:

*http://member IP address:port/hazelcast/rest/maps/mapName/key*

I get data back that is not in json format. Is it possible to return this data in json?

Answer (score 0):

I think that currently the endpoint always returns the plain text only. I don't see any possibility of choosing the response structure based on the input parameters (that's the part [in the code](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/internal/ascii/rest/HttpGetCommandProcessor.java#L174)).